# #Value error while converting cell value into a date

Tags: excel-formula

I'm getting an error while converting a date into a date with TEXT function from Excel.

What i'm trying to do is to I get the last non blank cell in a column then with the row number i can access the cell which contains a date. When I apply my formula i get an #value! error. The error pops up when converting the cell value (which is a date) into a date.

```
TEXT(INDEX(Form1!$F:$F;MATCH("zz";Form1!I:I) );"jj/mm/aaaa")
```

Almost every time the sheet "Form1" is changed than i get an error. Sometimes even when without being it changed. Pls help me.

Comment: Hi!, could you please send the sample data snaps to clarify your issue.

Comment: I already figured it out, i just had to make the cell format as date and removed text function and it worked. The final formula is INDEX(Form1!$F:$F;MATCH("zz";Form1!I:I)

Comment: Great! Excel Mastro !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded solution for the same by question owner himself.

The exact formulas is.

**Cell Format** as `Date`

```
=INDEX(Form1!$F:$F;MATCH("zz";Form1!I:I)
```

Solved